# Concrete5 Clear Cache - Not working - paths are all broken

Tags: php, caching, concrete5

I have recently been having troubles after I restored a backup version of the site.

The problem I have is that alot of paths for various elements have references to cached files and those paths.

Here is an example of a stylesheet that is wrong.
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/application/files/cache/css/rainmaker/main.css" media="screen">`

How do I clear the cache and stop it from doing this over and over.

Here is what I have attempted (nothing worked):

I tried clicking the "Clear Cache" button.

I ensured caching is turned of in the settings.

I deleted the cache folder from the server directly.

**But as soon as I refresh the page it creates a brand new cache folder on the server with all the same stuff in it.**

**How do I actually clear out the cache and perhaps make it re-cache everything?**

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you login to the admin account, go to Dashboard -> System & Settings and turn off all the caches under Cache & Speed Settings, then go to Clear Cache and clear it (you could now delete the /application/files/cache directory).  If you go to the front end then it should re-build the cache automatically.  Then you can turn your caches back on.